# method call is not working in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I tried a lot before putting this Question here.

```
Messaging msg = new Messaging();

msg.appendToMessageHistorysend(FriendList.ownusername, str);
```

I am calling appendToMessageHistorysend function from another Activity to messaging class

```
public void appendToMessageHistorysend(String username, String message) {
        if (username != null && message != null) {

            username1 = "<font color=#FF66CC>" + "<b>" + username + "<b/>"
                    + ":  " + "</font>";

            message1 = "<font color=#ffcc00>" + message + "&#13;&#10;"
                    + "<br/>" + "</font>";

            Thread thread = new Thread() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                                    if (messageHistoryText != null) {
                            messageHistoryText.append(Html
                                    .fromHtml(username1));
                            messageHistoryText.append(Html
                                    .fromHtml(message1));
                        }

                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(mCon, "hey yo you are null",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        }

                    });
                }

            };
            thread.start();

        }
    }
```

here is the called function and i am getting error like below

```
    01-21 15:21:42.552: E/AndroidRuntime(16751): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 15:21:42.552: E/AndroidRuntime(16751): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 15:21:42.552: E/AndroidRuntime(16751):    at at.vcity.androidim.Messaging$7$1.run(Messaging.java:515)
01-21 15:21:42.552: E/AndroidRuntime(16751):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-21 15:21:42.552: E/AndroidRuntime(16751):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-21 15:21:42.552: E/AndroidRuntime(16751):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 15:21:42.552: E/AndroidRuntime(16751):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4812)
01-21 15:21:42.552: E/AndroidRuntime(16751):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 15:21:42.552: E/AndroidRuntime(16751):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 15:21:42.552: E/AndroidRuntime(16751):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
01-21 15:21:42.552: E/AndroidRuntime(16751):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
01-21 15:21:42.552: E/AndroidRuntime(16751):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-21 15:21:44.704: E/Trace(17053): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

please give your valuable time and i am very thankfull to every body.

Comment: You need `Context` to display Toast in other class.

Comment: getapplicationcontex()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `Context` to display `Toast` in other class.

So you need to create single argument constructor in your **Messaging** class like

```
private Context mCon;
public void Messaging(Context con){
 this.mCon=con;
}
```

then used like

```
Toast.makeText(mCon, "Testing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and called like

```
Messaging msg = new Messaging(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: thank you solution work...but i come across one new Issue while assigning value to view.

Comment: Yo. I am Updating my Question with error log please check.

Comment: @Riturajsuman  `messageHistoryText=null` over in `Messaging` class

Comment: yeah its showing null but i initialise that properly.then why is this giving error like this..

Comment: @Riturajsuman Becoz you are not able access that in `Messaging` class. if you want then pass as second argument to `Messaging` constructor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69285/discussion-between-m-d-and-rituraj-suman).